# P vs NP: Assuming P = NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np, polynomial-time

Lets assume $P = NP$. Can we say if every language $L \in P$, then $L \in NPC$?

I read $P \subseteq NP$, which means that $L\in NP$. So I know for example, that a language can be $NP \text{ hard}$, but it doesn't have to be in $NP$, e.g. $HALT$.

But what about the case above. Is the language also $NPC$?

Comment: [A diagram.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/P_np_np-complete_np-hard.svg/800px-P_np_np-complete_np-hard.svg.png)

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: Could you also explain it with a few sentences? I saw the same diagram on wikipedia, but I could not find an explanation for it.

Comment: This question is answered in [the Wikipedia article on NP-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete); see the diagram on the upper-right.  I have higher expectations for the amount of research you do on your own before asking.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Every* problem in $P$ can be reduced to any other problem in $P$ using polynomial-time reductions (since the reduction is allowed to do polynomial work, it can just solve the problem itself).

If $P=NP$, then it follows that every* problem in $NP$ can be reduced to any* other problem in $NP$ -- in other words, every* problem in $NP$ is $NP$-complete.  This implies that if $L \in P$ and if $P=NP$ then* $L$ is $NP$-complete.

Footnote *: There is an exception for the empty language ($\emptyset$) and the universal language ($\Sigma^*$).  For purposes of gaining a rough conceptual understanding, this technical detail can probably be safely ignored.

Comment: Hi D.W.,
I have a question to a statement of yours. You said:" If $P=NP$, then it follows that every problem in NP can be reduced to any other problem in NP..."
What about if $P!=NP$. Does it still follow that every Problem in $NP$ can be reduced to any other problem in $NP$?

Comment: @user2965601, no, if $P\neq NP$, then there are problems in $NP$ and not in $P$ that are _not_ $NP$-complete.